Azure storage account migration stuck while converting from LRS to ZRS
We have Azure storage accounts with LRS redundancy. Attempted to change redundancy from LRS to ZRS. But the migration seems stuck and the status is submitted for conversion. I have initiated the conversion 5 days back. Generally how much time the migration will take to complete?



How big (in terabytes) is your storage-account? Are any objects/blobs currently in a Leased state? Are any VMs using this storage-account for Disks?

0 TB. Nothing in a leased state. No VMs using this storage accounts for disks.

@VenkatV, I require to migrate ZRS, not GZRS.

Yes, after initiation from LRS to ZRS, the conversion could still take up to 72 hours to begin, but there is no SLA for completion of a conversion. If its stuck more than 5days, check the ms doc to know the causes.


Azure storage account migration stuck while converting from LRS to ZRS.

According to this MS-Document.
Customer-initiated conversions can be performed in supported regions through the Azure portal, PowerShell, or the Azure CLI. Once initiated, it may take up to 72 hours for the conversion process to start.
Also, they mentioned

There is no specific Service Level Agreement (SLA) for the completion of Azure Storage account conversions from LRS to ZRS.
The time required for a migration depends on factors such as the amount of data, the replication processes, and the backend infrastructure workload.
If you need more control over the timing is needed, Manual migration is a more predictable alternative. This involves creating a new storage account and transferring data manually using tools like AzCopy or the Azure Storage Data Movement library.

Also, you can check the status of service health in the portal to see if there is any ongoing maintenance or issue.
Here's how you can access the Azure Service Health dashboard:

Go to the Azure portal  and sign in with your Azure account.
In the left-hand menu, click on "Help + support".
In the Help + support menu, under the "Health" section, click on "Service Health".

If the issue will remain same, you can raise azure support request with account details to review the backend logs and take it further.
